# OpenCV and ROS: NULL Pointer error in cvMAT

Tags: c++, opencv, ros

I'm using the following to to detect the position, orientation of two colored objects.
Everything works well unless the camera is unable to fine any of those two objects(yellow and blue) or when I put my hand in front of the camera. It throws the following error:

OpenCV Error: Null pointer (NULL array pointer is passed) in cvGetMat, file /tmp/buildd/libopencv-2.3.1+svn6514+branch23/modules/core/src/array.cpp, line 2382
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /tmp/buildd/libopencv-2.3.1+svn6514+branch23/modules/core/src/array.cpp:2382: error: (-27) NULL array pointer is passed in function cvGetMat

I'd be grateful if someone could help me resolve this error.

Thank You

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv/highgui.h>



#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <math.h>

#include <geometry_msgs/Twist.h>

#define MAX_CONTOUR_LEVELS 5 //This will be used when displaying contours
#define PI 3.14159265
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
// Class Definition
class color_control {
public:
    void mainLoop1();
    void mainLoop2();
    double R_X, R_Y; /* red center of gravity x,y in the frame normalized from -1.0 to 1.0 */
    int C_C;
    double setSpeed( double, double );
    void do_some_magic( IplImage* , int , int , int , int );

    color_control()
    {
      // node creation in root-namespace 
      ros::NodeHandle m_nodeHandle("/");

      m_commandPublisher = m_nodeHandle.advertise<geometry_msgs::Twist> ("cmd_vel", 20);
    }

    ~color_control()
    {
      cvDestroyWindow("result");
    }



protected:

    ros::NodeHandle m_nodeHandle;

    // Publisher und Membervariable für die Fahrbefehle
    ros::Publisher m_commandPublisher;
    geometry_msgs::Twist m_roombaCommand;

};

int abort_error_handler(int status, char const* func_name, char const* err_msg, char const* file_name, int line, void*) {
cout << "ERROR: in " << func_name << "(" << file_name << ":" << line << ") Message: " << err_msg << endl;
abort();
}

IplImage* GetThresholdedImage1(IplImage* img)
{
    IplImage* imgHSV = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img), 8, 3);
    cvCvtColor(img, imgHSV, CV_BGR2HSV);
    IplImage* imgThreshed1=cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img),8,1);
    //cvInRangeS(imgHSV, cvScalar(20, 100, 100), cvScalar(30, 255, 255), imgYellow);
    cvInRangeS(imgHSV, cvScalar(22, 100, 100), cvScalar(32, 255, 255), imgThreshed1);
    cvReleaseImage(&imgHSV);
    //cvAdd(imgYellow,imgGreen,imgThreshed);
    //if (imgThreshed1 != NULL)
            return imgThreshed1;
    //cvShowImage( "result", imgThreshed1 );
}

IplImage* GetThresholdedImage2(IplImage* img)
{
    IplImage* imgHSV = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img), 8, 3);
    cvCvtColor(img, imgHSV, CV_BGR2HSV);
    IplImage* imgThreshed2=cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img),8,1);
    //cvInRangeS(imgHSV, cvScalar(20, 100, 100), cvScalar(30, 255, 255), imgYellow);
    cvInRangeS(imgHSV, cvScalar(100,100,100^3),cvScalar(120,255,255^3), imgThreshed2);
    cvReleaseImage(&imgHSV);
    //cvAdd(imgYellow,imgGreen,imgThreshed);
    //if (imgThreshed2 == NULL)
            return imgThreshed2;


}

// find the largest contour (by area) from a sequence of contours and return a
// pointer to that item in the sequence

CvSeq* findLargestContour(CvSeq* contours){

  CvSeq* current_contour = contours;
  double largestArea = 0;
  CvSeq* largest_contour = NULL;

  // check we at least have some contours

  if (contours == NULL){return NULL;}

  // for each contour compare it to current largest area on
  // record and remember the contour with the largest area
  // (note the use of fabs() for the cvContourArea() function)

  while (current_contour != NULL){

      double area = fabs(cvContourArea(current_contour));

      if(area > largestArea){
          largestArea = area;
          largest_contour = current_contour;
      }

      current_contour = current_contour->h_next;
  }

  // return pointer to largest

  return largest_contour;

}

// normalize center of color to propulsion command
double color_control::setSpeed( double center, double width ){


  double normedCenter = (12.0*center/width) - 6.0;
    //ROS_INFO("normed center: %f", normedCenter);
  double retval = 0.0;

  if ( fabs( normedCenter ) > 1.0 ){
      retval = (trunc( normedCenter )/10.0 );
  }
  return retval;

}

//
// comments R 4 mollycoddles, guess what i'm doing!
// 
// Please help me ! I need someone writing comments. Thanx
//
void color_control::do_some_magic( IplImage* img, int red, int green, int blue, int tolerance) {

    int radius = 20 ;

    int width = img->width;
    int height = img->height;
    int channels = img->nChannels;
    int step = img->widthStep;

    unsigned char redP = 0, greenP = 0, blueP = 0;
    double S_x = 0.0 ;
    double S_y = 0.0 ;
    int red_difference, green_difference, blue_difference = 255;

    C_C = 0 ;

    for(int y=0;y<height;y++) {
        for(int x=0;x<width;x++) {
          blueP = img->imageData[y*step+x*channels+0] ;
          greenP = img->imageData[y*step+x*channels+1] ;
          redP = img->imageData[y*step+x*channels+2] ;

      red_difference = fabs(red - (int)redP);
      green_difference = fabs(green - (int)greenP);
      blue_difference = fabs(blue - (int)blueP);

      if ( (red_difference + green_difference + blue_difference) < tolerance ) {
         C_C++ ;
         S_x += x;
         S_y += y;

         //ROS_INFO( "Difference to target color: %i", (red_difference + green_difference + blue_difference) );
        }

        }
     }

    S_x = S_x / (C_C) ;
    S_y = S_y / (C_C) ;

    R_X = setSpeed( S_x, img->width );
    R_Y = setSpeed( S_y, img->height );

    // for monitoring, draw a circle and display the respective picture
    CvPoint center;
    center.x = S_x;
    center.y = S_y;
    cvCircle( img, center, radius, CV_RGB( 255 - red, 255 - green, 255 - blue ) , 3, 8, 0 );
    cvShowImage( "result", img );
}

// Main Loop
void color_control::mainLoop1() {
    // determines the number of frames per second
    ros::Rate loop_rate(20);
     int radius ;
    CvCapture* capture = 0;
    //IplImage *frame, *frame_copy = 0;
    IplImage* imgScribble=NULL;
    // open the camera
    capture = cvCaptureFromCAM( 0 );
    cvSetCaptureProperty(capture,CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 640);
    cvSetCaptureProperty(capture,CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 480);
    //capture = cvCaptureFromCAM( 1 );
    //cvRedirectError(abort_error_handler);



    // loop stops, e.g. if the node recieves a kill signal
    while (m_nodeHandle.ok())
    {
        IplImage* frame=0;
                    frame=cvQueryFrame(capture);

                    if(!frame)
                                break;
//                  if(imgScribble == NULL)
//                  {
//                      imgScribble=cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(frame),8,1);
//                  }


                    IplImage* imgYellowThresh = GetThresholdedImage1(frame);
                    IplImage* imgGreenThresh = GetThresholdedImage2(frame);



            //CvMemStorage and CvSeq are structures used for dynamic data collection. CvMemStorage contains pointers to the actual
            //allocated memory, but CvSeq is used to access this data. Here, it will hold the list of image contours.
            CvMemStorage *storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
            CvSeq *contours = 0;

            //Once we have a binary image, we can look for contours in it. cvFindContours will scan through the image and store connected contours in "sorage".
            //"contours" will point to the first contour detected. CV_RETR_TREE means that the function will create a contour hierarchy. Each contour will contain
            //a pointer to contours that are contained inside it (holes). CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE means that all the contours points will be stored. Finally, an offset
            //value can be specified, but we set it to (0,0).
            cvFindContours(imgYellowThresh, storage, &contours, sizeof(CvContour), CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, cvPoint(0,0));

            //This function will display contours on top of an image. We can specify different colours depending on whether the contour in a hole or not.
            CvSeq* largest_contour = NULL;
            largest_contour = findLargestContour(contours);

                //cvDrawContours(imgYellowThresh, largest_contour, CV_RGB(255,255,255), CV_RGB(0,255,0), MAX_CONTOUR_LEVELS, 3, CV_AA, cvPoint(0,0));
if(largest_contour!=NULL) {
                cvDrawContours(imgYellowThresh, largest_contour, CV_RGB(255,255,255), CV_RGB(0,255,0), 0, 2, 8, cvPoint(0,0));

}

            static int posX_Yellow=0;
            static int posY_Yellow=0;


            //int lastX=posX;
            //int lastY=posY;

           CvMoments moments1,cenmoments1;
           double M00, M01, M10;

           cvMoments(largest_contour,&moments1);
           M00 = cvGetSpatialMoment(&moments1,0,0);
           M10 = cvGetSpatialMoment(&moments1,1,0);
           M01 = cvGetSpatialMoment(&moments1,0,1);
           posX_Yellow = (int)(M10/M00);
           posY_Yellow = (int)(M01/M00);

          double theta = 0.5 * atan(
                    (2 * cvGetCentralMoment(&moments1, 1, 1)) /
                    (cvGetCentralMoment(&moments1, 2, 0) -  cvGetCentralMoment(&moments1, 0, 2)));
                theta = (theta / PI) * 180;

                // fit an ellipse (and draw it)

                if (largest_contour->total >= 6) // can only do an ellipse fit
                                                 // if we have > 6 points
                {
                    CvBox2D box = cvFitEllipse2(largest_contour);
                    if ((box.size.width < imgYellowThresh->width) &&  (box.size.height < imgYellowThresh->height))
                    {
                        // get the angle of the ellipse correct (taking into account MS Windows
                        // seems to draw ellipses differently

                        box.angle =  270 - box.angle;
                        #ifndef WIN32
                            if( imgYellowThresh->origin ) {
                                box.angle = - box.angle;
                            }
                        #endif
                        cvEllipseBox(imgYellowThresh, box, CV_RGB(255, 255 ,255), 3, 8, 0 );
                    }
                }
              CvFont font;
              cvInitFont(&font, CV_FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1, 1 , 0, 2, 8 );

            #ifdef WIN32
                int height_offset = 20;
            #else
                int height_offset = 5;
            #endif
                char outputString[255];

                sprintf(outputString, "angle: %.10f", theta);
                cvPutText(imgYellowThresh, outputString,
                    cvPoint(10,imgYellowThresh->height - height_offset), &font, CV_RGB(255, 255,255));






                              CvMemStorage *storageG = cvCreateMemStorage(0);

    CvSeq *contoursG = 0;

        //Once we have a binary image, we can look for contours in it. cvFindContours will scan through the image and store connected contours in "sorage".
        //"contours" will point to the first contour detected. CV_RETR_TREE means that the function will create a contour hierarchy. Each contour will contain
        //a pointer to contours that are contained inside it (holes). CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE means that all the contours points will be stored. Finally, an offset
        //value can be specified, but we set it to (0,0).
        cvFindContours(imgGreenThresh, storageG, &contoursG, sizeof(CvContour), CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, cvPoint(0,0));

        //This function will display contours on top of an image. We can specify different colours depending on whether the contour in a hole or not.
        CvSeq* largest_contourG = NULL;
        largest_contourG = findLargestContour(contoursG);

if(largest_contourG!=NULL) {
            //cvDrawContours(imgYellowThresh, largest_contour, CV_RGB(255,255,255), CV_RGB(0,255,0), MAX_CONTOUR_LEVELS, 3, CV_AA, cvPoint(0,0));

            cvDrawContours(imgGreenThresh, largest_contourG, CV_RGB(255,255,255), CV_RGB(0,255,0), 0, 2, 8, cvPoint(0,0));
}
        //cvShowImage( "result2", imgGreenThresh );
    CvMoments moments2;
                               double M00g, M01g, M10g;

                               cvMoments(largest_contourG,&moments2);
                               M00g = cvGetSpatialMoment(&moments2,0,0);
                               M10g = cvGetSpatialMoment(&moments2,1,0);
                               M01g = cvGetSpatialMoment(&moments2,0,1);
                               static int posX_Green=0;
                                        static int posY_Green=0;
                                posX_Green = (int)(M10g/M00g);
                               posY_Green = (int)(M01g/M00g);

                               //printf("%d\n",M00g);
   //ROS_INFO("position (%d,%d)\n",posX_Yellow,posY_Yellow);
   //ROS_INFO("position (%d,%d)\n",posX_Green,posY_Green);

            //do_some_magic( frame , 0, 0, 0, 100);




//          if(lastX>0 && lastY>0 && posX>0 && posY>0)
//                  {
//                      cvLine(imgScribble,cvPoint(posX,posY),cvPoint(lastX,lastY),cvScalar(0,255,255), 5);
//                  }
//          cvAdd(frame,imgScribble,frame);
            cv::Point centerY(posX_Yellow,posY_Yellow);
            //centerY.x = posX_Yellow;
            //centerY.y = posY_Yellow;
            //radius = sqrt(areaY/3.14);
            cvCircle( frame, centerY, 10, CV_RGB( 255, 255, 255) , 3, 8, 0 );

            cv::Point centerG(posX_Green,posY_Green);
            //centerG.x = posX_Green;
            //centerG.y = posY_Green;
            cv::Point diff = centerY - centerG;
            //radius = sqrt(areaG/3.14);
            cvCircle( frame, centerG, 10, CV_RGB( 255, 255, 255) , 3, 8, 0 );
            //float angle = atan2(centerY,centerX);
            int slope = ((diff.y)/(diff.x));
            int len = cv::sqrt(diff.x*diff.x + diff.y*diff.y);
            double newdist = (len / 2000000);
            cvLine(frame, centerY, centerG, CV_RGB( 255, 255, 255), 5,8,0);
            //cvCircle( frame, diff, 10, CV_RGB( 255, 255, 255) , 3, 8, 0 );
            //ROS_INFO("angle :  %d\n",theta);
            //ROS_INFO("len: %d    slope: %d\n",len,slope);
            //printf("len: %f\n", slope);
            cvShowImage( "result", frame );
            cvShowImage( "result1", imgYellowThresh );
            cvShowImage( "result2", imgGreenThresh );

            if( cvWaitKey( 10 ) >= 0 )
                                    break;

         //ROS_INFO( "C_C: %d", C_C );



         // set driving direction and velocity
//       if (len > 50 || slope > 0)
//        {
//          m_roombaCommand.linear.x = 0.1;
//          m_roombaCommand.angular.z = 0.0;
//        } else {
//          m_roombaCommand.linear.x = 0.0;
//          m_roombaCommand.angular.z = 0.1;
//        }


         //
//      ROS_INFO("Forward: %f - Turning: %f", m_roombaCommand.linear.x, m_roombaCommand.angular.z);
//
//      // send the driving command to the roomba
        //m_commandPublisher.publish(m_roombaCommand);

    // spinOnce is doing the loop exactly once
    ros::spinOnce();
            //cvReleaseCapture( &capture );

    // sleep stops the process for approx ~50ms, to keep the timing for the looprate
    loop_rate.sleep();


    }

    //cvReleaseImage( &frame_copy );


}


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    //sleep(10);
    // Initialize
    ros::init(argc, argv, "color_control");

    ros::NodeHandle n;
    color_control f_g;
    f_g.mainLoop1();
    //color_control g_g;
    //g_g.mainLoop2();
    ros::spin();
    //cvRedirectError(abort_error_handler);
    return 0;




        //cvNamedWindow("Video");
        //cvNamedWindow("thresh");
    }
```

Comment: There is too much code to read and understand. Can you try to make a shorter example that has this error? Also please read http://sscce.org/

Comment: findlargestContour function is returning me null values when there is not colored object around. and thus the error. How can i avoid this so that program still runs without this error?

Comment: To make it clear for the OP: The question looks good, but the looooong code posted here reflects low appreciation for the community. Good questions are easy to read. For this one, someone has to read for 10 minutes, and that's too much

Comment: And a side comment: it looks that you took this code from somewhere, and do not have enough programming knowledge to work with it. I recommend to start learning C++, then move to the more complex things like computer vision

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `findlargestContour` you check the returned value for `NULL` when calling `cvDrawContours`. However, you use the returned value after that as well, without checking for `NULL`.

The simple solution is to add more checks for `NULL` before you use the returned value.